# Insecure rules in firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I understand it's not good to set your read and writes to all users on Firebase;
But what if you leave your reads to all and your writes to only authenticated users?

What is the worst thing that could happen?
Is it easy for someone to gain access to the firebase project?
I'm currently using cloud firestore.

Sorry if this seems a little dumb, I'm new to this:

Thanks,
Jacob

EDIT: Current Rules:

```
  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any authenticated user can read/write anything to Firestore. If you could share your existing rules and then explain what kind of rules you are looking for then we may be able to help.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I added my current rules, I'm trying to ask, how insecure is this actually? Is it likely someone will gain access to my firebase and read all the data and run up my reads?

Comment: Your current rules allow anyone including non-authenticated users to read your complete database. That may not be secure. Is there any specific collection that you want to be readable by everyone or so?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks for the help, i'm trying to ask, is it easy for someone to gain access. How would a non-authenticated user even be able to gain access to my database. Thanks,

Comment: But that is correct, I do only want one collection to be able to be read by non authenticated users. How would this look like? Thank you

Comment: They don't need to _gain_ access. You have made your data public. They just need to make a request either using the SDKs or REST API.

Comment: `match /collectionName/{docs=**} {  allow read: if true; }` This should allow users to read documents from the `collectionName` collection only. Read more at: [Fix insecure rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules)

Comment: So would the new version look like:?
`
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{docs=**} {  allow read: if true; }
  }
}
`

Comment: if you check for request.auth != null, then every user that is logged in can edit and read all the datas. Often you want to be more restrictive and limit the read / edit only to the data I own: you can do this with rules like that: 
match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

(compare user id of the ressource to the id currently authenticated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with Firebase for a long time and I've come to realize that the rules are a very good way to prevent unauthorized access to your data, by any third party - especially when used in tandem with rules set within your Application (be it Web, iOS or Android).

Personally, I usually set my rules to the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents { match /{document=**} { 
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null; 
}
```

This means that *only* logged in users are allowed to access the data and write data as well.

If, instead, you want users to access the data *without* being logged in but only write data if they're logged in, then I would suggest these rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents { match /{document=**} { 
    allow read;
    allow write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

In terms of how easy it is to access a Firestore Database when not authorized to:
Google has done a good job at keeping things secure.

Setting up these rules and some other checks within your Application is enough to keep things secure.